# Bitwise operation and arrow function return statement

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, arrow-functions

I have a byte, and I want to increment bits left to the first bit by 1 (the context is a small Conway's Game of Life).

Example: 11 is `0000 1011`:

1. I want to increment `101`
2. 5 + 1 = 6 is `110`
3. reset the first bit to initial state
4. the byte is now `0000 1101` which is 13

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to make `addNeighbour` proceed as a **void** method (I couldn't find a way to **not** return `num`)?
- Is there a better way to perform `addNeighbour` operations :

```js
const getBinaryRepresentation = (number) => {
    let str = "";
    for (let i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        ((number & (1 << i)) != 0) ? str += "1" : str += "0";
    }
    console.log(str)
}

let num = 5; 
getBinaryRepresentation(num) // 0000 0101
const addNeighbour = (num) => {
    const isAlive = num & 1;
    const neighbours = num >> 1;

    num = (neighbours + 1) << 1;
    if (isAlive === 1) num |= (1 << 0)
    return num;
}
num = addNeighbour(num);
getBinaryRepresentation(num) // 0000 0111
```

Comment: If you remove `return num` it will not return anything, aka returns void...

Comment: yes but the actual value of `num`is not affected, `getBinaryRepresentation(num)` will return 0000 0101

Comment: By "first bit", you mean the LSB?

Comment: @Bergi Totally !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make `addNeighbour` proceed as a void method (I couldn't find a way to not return `num`)?

No. If you don't return the result, you cannot assign it back to `num`. And you cannot pass a reference to the `let num` (or any other) variable that the function should read from and store into.

> Is there a better way to perform `addNeighbour` operations

Yes. Adding `1` at the second-least significant bit position is just the same as adding `2` at the least signification position. Replace your code with

```
num += 2;
```

Put in other terms,

```
  (((num >> 1) + 1) << 1) | (num & 1)
≡ (((num >> 1) << 1) + (1 << 1)) | (num & 1)
≡ ((num & ~1) + (1 << 1)) | (num & 1)
≡ ((num & ~1) | (num & 1)) + (1 << 1)
≡ num + (1 << 1)
```

Comment: This triggers my LISP ptsd...

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't have `byRef` on simple values in javascript you can't return void and change variable outside of the function.

You could optimize a little the function though, by reusing variables:

```js
const getBinaryRepresentation = (number) => {
  return console.log(number.toString(2).padStart(8, 0));
}

let num = 5;
getBinaryRepresentation(num) // 0000 0101
const addNeighbour = (num) => {
    const isAlive = num & 1;
    num >>= 1;
    num = (num + 1) << 1;
    return num | isAlive;
}
num = addNeighbour(num);
getBinaryRepresentation(num) // 0000 0111
```

Comment: Indeed more elegant but adding +2 like Bergi suggested seems much more appropriate to my use case.

Comment: yes, it is. The simplest solution is often the best solution...